# Resetable CountDownLatch

Tags: java, multithreading, countdownlatch, phaser

I have a problem that I want to solve. I have one thread that must wait a number of a variable number of async threads to finish their execution finishes and after that, It must execute and again stay in the wait state until the other threads finish their execution.

***Example:***

Thread A waits until Threads B and C finishes their execution. After that Thread A must be executed and other threads should wait. This is a cycle that repeats n times.

```
ThreadA{
   public void run(){
      while(true){
         if(queue.peek() % 2 == 0){
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            doStuff();
         }
      }
   }
}
ThreadB{
   public void run(){
      while(true){
          if(queue.peek() % 2 == 0){
             doStuff();
             phaser.arrive();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Thread C has the same pseudocode as Thread B.

I need synchronized something like this: Thread A must executed only after Thread B and Thread C perform their execution and Thread B and Thread C must wait Thread A finalize its execution.

I tryied using Phaser as mentioned in code above with Phaser but I din't get the result expected.

Could someone give an example?

I am using Java 8 and I looking for a resettable form of CountDownLatch, maybe using phaser.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the case. Can you please specify an exact End-to-end scenario?

Comment: The scenario is as written .. Thread B and Thread C must complete their work, then Thread A will run, when Thread A finishes it starts again, thread B and thread C must complete their work, then thread A will run...  The "N" times is forever, or bounded ??

Comment: Lots of [good ideas here](https://ducmanhphan.github.io/2020-03-20-Waiting-threads-to-finish-completely-in-Java/)

Comment: You need to be more specific in your scenario. Are threads running in a loop ? can you provide some actually pseudo code or something

Comment: Both [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) and [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) will do what you need, they even support actions on countdown / phase advance. `CyclicBarrier` is older and slower, while `Phaser` is new, fast, and supports a richer API. That said, each has their place.